# Disabling repeating battery failure alarms on an APC Smart-UPS

Tags: linux, battery, ups

I have an old APC SU700I with batteries which were failed on the self-test. [Its manual](http://www.apc.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z8LLF/ASTE-6Z8LLF_R3_EN.pdf) says the following:

> THE REPLACE BATTERY/BATTERY DISCONNECTED LED IS ILLUMINATED
>
> Failure of a battery self-test.
>
> The UPS emits short beeps for one minute and the replace battery
> LED illuminates. The UPS repeats the alarm every five hours.
> Perform the self-test procedure after the battery has charged for 24 hours to
> confirm the replace battery condition. The alarm stops and the LED
> clears if the battery passes the self-test.

I did the manual self-test (still failing) but it seems that the UPS does not repeat the alarm after five hours. I would like to avoid repeating alarms while the new batteries arrive. How can I achieve this?

I have set `BEEPSTATE` to `N` (Never) a long time ago with [`apcupsd`](http://www.apcupsd.org/manual/) and it silences the power failure alarms well. I guess this setting applies only to power failure alarms since the first battery failure has an audible alarm.  On the other hand, the battery failure alarm does not seem repeating (so the manual probably is not completely accurate here) but I'm not sure about that and I wouldn't like to wake up in the middle of the night if it repeats the alarm later.

Comment: One option is to take it apart and temporarily disconnect the beeper.  But I think the easier solution is to overnight the new batteries.